# Connected IBOutlets are not initialized

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I've implemented custom `UICollectionViewCell` class in Swift, created storyboard with UICollectionViewCotroller, assigned my custom controller class, custom cell class, cell id etc... Basically everything required to make UICollectionViewController work.

In storyboard cell prototype I've added few views and connected them as IBOutlets to my custom cell class:

[image]

here my IBOutlets in code (as you can see, they are connected):
[image]

I registered custom cell class in my controller too:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

When I dequeue my cell in code it returns cell of my custom type but both IBOutlets aren't initialised (equal `nil`)

```
    let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier,
    forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCollectionViewCell

    if let path = indexPath {
        // Crash here as imageView is nil
        cell.imageView.image = imagesArray[path.item] 
    }
```

Crashlog:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

if I put breakpoint on `if` statement above and do `po cell` I have this output:

```
(lldb) po cell
0x00007fa799f4cdf0
 {
  UIKit.UICollectionViewCell = {
    UIKit.UICollectionReusableView = {
      UIKit.UIView = {
        UIKit.UIResponder = {
          ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
  selectionView = nil
  imageView = nil
}
```

Any ideas why IBOutlets aren't initialised?

Answer (score 2):

It happens because IBOutlets are connected later, after `initWithCoder` has finished.

To setup your controls after they've been connected, you can override `- applyLayoutAttributes:` in your `UIColletionViewCell` subclass.

```
override func applyLayoutAttributes(layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    setupControls()
}
```

According to documentation, it's an empty method, meant to be overridden in order to apply custom layout attributes to the view. Sounds about right.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem starting in Beta5, though with xib not with storyboard.
In the xib case, it appears to be a problem with

```
init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

not picking up the default xib filename.  When I changed to an explicit nibName

```
init(nibName: "MyClass", bundle: nil)
```

then it started working again.  Could the the same issue with storyboard - if there's a way to force the storyboard name, I'd try that.

Answer (score 1):

Well , I also faced this problem , and my issues is solved by commenting **Register api of collection view** as following code snippet  . I believed that as we are using storyboard . and there we have given all information like (Class , outlets and identifier ) . so storyboard handle all this .

```
func configureCollectionView(isNib:Bool = false)
{
    if isNib
    {
        //collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "GalleryCell", bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    else
    {
        //collectionView.register(PhotoCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is beta 4 or 5, and I think it is based on the IBOutlets being optional, do you have initWithCoder overridden in the class? Even one that does nothing but call super? That being missing might be your problem.

Edit: Have you tried making sure the reuseIdentifiers all match up in the storyboards and code?

Comment: It is Beta5. In Beta5 IBOutlets are initialised (automatically on Ctrl-drag) as `IBOutlet weak var variableName: VarType`. Yes, I overrode initWithCoder. It is compile time error in Beta5 - you can't build your app if UIView subclass doesn't override it.

Comment: That's right. It doesn't just crash anymore, it's a real error.