# All IBOutlets become nil after switching to Xcode 6 Beta 5

Tags: swift, xcode6

For instance, there is a property in a view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
```

This property is `nil` inside `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`, so the app crashes at runtime.

It was working fine in Xcode 6 Beta 4. After I switched to Beta 5, it complained about the controller class `does not implement its superclass's required members`. So I added

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

And that compiler error disappeared. However, the app crashes for `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` because that `nameLabel` property is `nil` when I try to set its `text`.

I read through the release notes and could not figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150226/connected-iboutlets-are-not-initialized/25150932)
Now I see that it isn't only my problem but I don't believe that apple submitted Beta5 with such major bug...

Comment: is your controller `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: No, mine is subclassed from `UIViewController`

Comment: I am having all weired problems with Beta 5. I think i will revert to Beta 4 and wait for Beta 6

Comment: I was told the workaround by someone at Apple. See my revised answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue in Beta5. It appears to be a problem where

```
init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```

is not mapping nil to the default nibName.  When I changed to an explicit nibName then it worked.  Specifically in my case, using the new ?? operator:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
   // beta5 workaround: replace nil with explicit name of xib file
   let nib = nibNameOrNil ?? "MyViewController"

   super.init(nibName: nib, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

   // local initialization here
}
```

caused it to magically work again.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, because (1) it places the responsibility on the shoulders of the view controller itself, (2) it uses the cool new `??` operator. :)

Comment: Ugh, I spent too much time battling with the compiler and then puzzling over this crash. Thank you.

Comment: This bug is fixed in iOS 9 beta 4, so this workaround become mercifully unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's a temporary bug. The workaround turns out to be: Declare your view controller in such a way as to override name mangling, like this:

```
@objc(ViewController) ViewController : UIViewController { // or whatever its name is
```

See also: [Are view controllers with nib files broken in ios 8 beta 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149604/are-view-controllers-with-nib-files-broken-in-ios-8-beta-5/25152545#25152545)

**EDIT** This bug is fixed in iOS 9 beta 4.