# Container View - No Outlet Possible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I have a ViewController with a ScrollView in it, which has 2 ContainerViews in it. Now, every ContainerView loads a ViewController.
And in this ViewControllers (SubController from the ContainerViews) its impossible to do Outlets. 
I get the little circles at the outlets, so the reference exists, but setting the text of a label for example, always results in the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I've done the connection 10 times, with all possible names. Restarted xcode multiple times, still not working.

This answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28479934/2414069

EDIT: (below code is pseudo, everything is in the place it should..)

```
@IBOutlet weak var pinInfo_name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pinInfo_address: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var pinInfo_comment: UITextView!

self.pinInfo_name.text = defaults.stringForKey("activePin_name")!
self.pinInfo_address.text = defaults.stringForKey("activePin_address")!
self.pinInfo_comment.text = defaults.stringForKey("activePin_comment")!
```

SOULUTION:
Ok I slept about it, and found my error within 10 minutes: I wanted to change the .text properties from a object I created in another ViewController. I still have no Idea how to do that, buts thats a story for another time.

***tl dr***

Access right

Comment: Can you show the code of how you declare the outlet, how you set the text, and also a screenshot of the storyboard where you attached those outlets?

Comment: @almas updated the post

Comment: Why is all that code below your outlets just there? It is required for it to be in a function (all the non-outlet code).

Answer (score 0):

As the link in your question points out, having multiple view controllers in your storyboard with the same class could cause this. Did you check that:

1. The child view controllers do not have the same class as each other
2. The child view controllers do not have the same class as the parent view controller

I made a test project and the I could connect the outlets of the `UILabel`s in the child view controller to their respective `UIViewController` subclasses without any problem.

Here's my example:

[image]

Comment: the ViewController containing the 2 ContainerViews has the class "ContainerViewController". The 2 ContainerView have the classes "LeftContainer" and "RightContainer".

Comment: I see.. I added a photo in case it helps of my setup which worked.

Comment: Thanks! Whats the Class of the ViewController containing the 2 Containers?

Comment: I just left it as a plain UIViewController (no subclass), but it could be anything.

Comment: Thats exactly the same setup I have then... Thats so weird, been searching the whole evening for a solution

Comment: did you find the solution to this problem? I'm having the same issue