# Passing data from Side Menu back to its original View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have a "Country" `ViewController` with two `ContainerViews`: Side Menu (`TocVC`) and Data Screen (`CountryDetailsVC`) on it. Button that controls Side Menu toggling is located in Navigation bar.

Side Menu has a `TableView` and upon `didSelectRowAt indexPath` I would like pass its `String` value back to Data Screen and assign it to a `Label` on it.

This is what I've tried:

`TocVC`:

```
var selectedItem:String = ""
...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedItem = contents[indexPath.row]
        let VC = CountryDetailsVC()
        VC.labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)
    }
```

`CountryDetailsVC`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
...

func labelUpdate(dataFrom: String) {
        self.label.text = dataFrom
    }
```

But I'm getting `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` as I understand because `TocVC` passed data but `CountryDetailsVC` didn't "refresh" itself and run the function.

What is the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: Storyboard screenshot
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlpUJ.png)

EDIT1: Updated code.

`Country`:

```
let detailsVc = CountryDetailsVC()
```

`TocVC`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedItem = contents[indexPath.row]

        Country().detailsVc.labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)
```

`CountryDetailsVC`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func labelUpdate(dataFrom: String) {
        print("dataFrom: \(dataFrom)")
        self.label.text = dataFrom
    }
```

The function prints out `dataFrom` string to the console but crashes on the next line trying to assign `dataFrom` to `label.text`.
When I change `label: UILabel!` to `label: UILabel?` it doesn't crash but not changing text either.
Maybe it has something to do with [this similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28479934/6396301)?

EDIT2: Updated code. Reference to `self` in segue to `TocVC`. Still doesn't work.

`Country`:

```
let detailsVc = CountryDetailsVC()
...
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue .destination is TocVC {
        let vc = segue.destination as? TocVC
        vc?.countryVC = self
    }
}
```

`TocVC`:

```
var countryVC: Country?
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedItem = contents[indexPath.row]

        Country().detailsVc.labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)
```

`CountryDetailsVC`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func labelUpdate(dataFrom: String) {
        print("dataFrom: \(dataFrom)")
        self.label.text = dataFrom
    }
```

Comment: where you are creating CountryDetailsVC object first time ? you need that object to call labelUpdate method.

Comment: I think the issue is you creating a new instance of your view controller by calling `let VC = CountryDetailsVC()`, which is not in the view hierarchy and therefor its `label` property is `nil` when you are trying to set the text. Are you using Storyboard or where do you instantiate the view controllers?

Comment: I've created View Controllers for Menu and Detail Screen in storyboard. Screenshot attached.

Comment: @06153 You should be be passing the value to the existing CountryDetailsVC(), not to the new instance. Get the existing from the parent.

Comment: @Anuraj you mean `CountryDetailsVC().labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)`? It shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance of `CountryDetailsVC` in `tableView(:didSelectRowAt:)`, you should store a reference to `CountryDetailsVC` in your parent view controller in a variable, for example in `prepare(for:sender:)` of the embed segue and then call your function on that variable later on.

Comment: Perhaps I should've mentioned it earlier: I'm not really experienced with Swift. Do I understand you correctly: I prepare a segue to `CountryDetailsVC` in `CountryVC` and store a variable like `let vc = segue.destination as? CountryDetailsVC` in there. Then I call a function from `tableView(:didSelectRowAt:)` to pass value to that segue, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. But you should store the `vc` as class variable of your `CountryVC` so you can access it later. You could then also in `prepare(for:sender:)` pass a reference to `CountryVC` itself to `TocVC` (let's call it `countryVC`) and then in your `tableView(:didSelectRowAt:)` call `countryVC.vc.labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)`

Comment: Okay, I've followed your recommendation but it seems I've messed something up. Function `func labelUpdate(dataFrom: String) {
        print("dataFrom: \(dataFrom)")
        self.label.text = dataFrom
    }`  in `CountryDetailsVC` now prints proper value of `dataFrom ` but when trying to assign it to label in the next line it still has the same error.

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes you made? The issue is most likely that `self.label` is still nil, because you are not accessing the VC instantiated via Storyboard.

Comment: I've updated my code. Segue works, function is being called but there is some problem with `label.text`

Comment: `Country().detailsVc.labelUpdate(dataFrom: selectedItem)` this line will once again create a new instance of your `Country` view controller. You need to pass a reference to itself to the `TocVC`. See my second comment.

Comment: I've passed a reference to `self` to `TocVC` but it had no effect. Sorry if I got it wrong again. Could you please share an example code?

Comment: Eventually I got rid of `ContryDetailsVC` and created a label in `Country` instead. It worked smoothly. Thank you for your help, your hint about passing reference to `self` helped me to figure it out.